# Error in data.frame(smoothness_mean = rep(seq(from = 0.05, to = 0.15)), : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Tags: r

> Error in data.frame(smoothness_mean = rep(seq(from = 0.05, to = 0.15)),  : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

what above comment means?

```
cancer1 <-data.frame(smoothness_mean = rep(seq(from = 0.05, 
                                               to = 0.15),
                                       length.out=100,4),
                 radius_mean = mean(cancer$radius_mean),
                 texture_mean = mean(cancer$texture_mean),
                 concave.points_mean = rep(c(0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08),0.10))
```

Comment: It means that the lengths of your inputs are not all the same, and the API you are calling is expecting this to be the case.  So, check all your inputs.

Comment: `rep(c(0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08),0.10)` has length = 0. I think there's something wrong with the first `smoothness_mean = rep()` too - it just generates 100 x 0.05, which does not look like the intention.

Comment: `rep(c(0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08),0.10)` will return an empty array. Do you mean `rep(c(0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.10),10)` ?

Comment: i found the solution for the problem , thank you for all the help